# Extracting Hour and Minutes In RedShift Within Same Function

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to find rows that came in before 7:30 pm (as part of a CASE WHEN). The below just has it at 8.  Any idea how to get this to be 7:30?

```
  extract(dayofweek from convert_timezone('EST', call_start_time)) in (6) and
extract(hour from convert_timezone('EST', call_start_time))
>=8 and extract(hour from convert_timezone('EST', ${TABLE}.call_start_time)) <20
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to test if the call_start_time is after 7:30pm EST on ANY day, right?

If so I think you just want to create an interval between the call_start_time and the beginning of that day - call_start_time - date_trunc('day', call_start_time).  (Or if you like trunc(timestamp) will give you the date.)  Then compare this to the time of day value you want - interval '13 hours 30 minutes'.  (13 hours is 19:00 minus 6 hour time zone difference.)

Have I read you question / intent correctly?

====================================

It looks like there is a need to provide a code example.  The simplest way to share this is with a sqlfiddle but that means that the syntax will be Postgresql not native Redshift.  For the parts of the SQL in question this isn't a change - working with timezones is different but that is handled by an area not in the "interval" calculations.

```
With prep as (
select *,  (t at time zone 'UTC') at time zone 'EST' as est_t, 
  date_trunc('day', (t at time zone 'UTC') at time zone 'EST') as est_t_date
from fred)
select n, t from prep
where extract(dow from (t at time zone 'UTC') at time zone 'EST') in (6)
and est_t between est_t_date + interval '8 hours' 
  and est_t_date + interval '19 hours 30 minutes'
;
```

Live code example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5236b/2

Comment: Thanks for your response.   In this case it is a specific day of the week (extract(dayofweek from convert_timezone('EST', call_start_time)) in (6) ) , and if the call came in between 8 am and 7:30 pm.

Comment: Gotcha.  The last condition is a check on being before 8pm (independent of day), the first term checks the day.  I think you can replace the last 2 conditions with a time interval BETWEEN (interval is between interval '2 hours' and '13 hours 30 minutes').  Is what I'm proposing make sense or is a code segment needed?

Comment: I am not totally sure I am following how this might work... if a call came in at 7:29 pm, it still should be included, but the interval to the end period would be 1 minute, if I am following the logic proposed.

Comment: Added code (Postgres to my answer).  You can play with it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5236b/2  This is in Postgres SQL which is a little different than Redshift but hopefully this gets the idea across.

Comment: thank you so much Bill for taking the time to answer this question for me and share the sql.  just getting back to this now.  i was updating my query and realized i could just  do, which fit in a little easier in my existing case when, and that resolved it: concat(extract(hour from convert_timezone('EST', call_start_time)),  
    extract(minutes from convert_timezone('EST', call_start_time))) <1930